# Steps for Moving Multiple WordPress Installs to a Multisite Install?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

*(**Moderator's Note:** Original title was: "Steps to move multiple wordpress installations to a WP MU installation")*

Any tips on moving multiple WordPress installations to a single Multisite[1] installation?

[1] *Multisite is the new name for WPMU.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record MU functionality was merged into core and is now referred to as `multisite`.

Codex has guide at [Migrating Multiple Blogs into WordPress 3.0 Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite)

Answer (score 6):

It's not really all that hard.

1. setup the new blog on the MU install
2. import the content from the old blog
3. check content and permalinks to make sure it's all there
4. map the domain
5. have a beer

I've done it a number of times and never really had issues.

Comment: Isn't there a little step missing before step #2, though I appreciate #5.

Comment: and what step would that be? you mean export the content from the old site? I just kinda figured that was an obvious one since you had to import the content.

Answer (score 6):

A couple extra handy links if you want everything in the db and have loads of images (there's some gotchas).

- [**Importing a single WP blog to a WPMu Installation**](http://bavatuesdays.com/importing-a-single-wp-blog-to-a-wpmu-installation/)
- [**Migrating single WordPress installations into multisite networks**](http://sillybean.net/wordpress/migrating-single-wordpress-installations-into-multisite-networks/)

Otherwise, it's just like Curtis says. Export / Import.